# Should I use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or System.Environment.CurrentDirectory?

Tags: c#, exception

I have two exe files in the same folder, I can run exe2 from a button in exe1. Today I was observing a customer over a remote (terminal services) session and exe2 failed to run 'File not found' error, yet exe1 was in the same directory when we checked. So should I be using [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) or [System.Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)?

Thanks

Comment: @Jade M
How are you executing your exe1 at terminal?

Comment: I want to add my two cents by saying that `string.GetFullPath(path)` uses `Environment.CurrentDirectory` rather than `CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, to my surprise.

Answer (score 201):

If you want to find files in the same directory as your application, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is the correct choice.

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` is a value that can and will change throught the course of running your application.  For instance, using default parameters, the OpenFileDialog in WinForms will change this value to the directory where the file was selected from.

Comment: I used button1 to show OpenFileDialog, then button2 to show Environment.CurrentDirectory, but still show debug folder, why?

Answer (score 22):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns the directory from where the current application domain was loaded.
`System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns the current system directory.
In your case `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is the best solution.

Comment: To be clear, System.Environment.CurrentDirectory returns the current (process-specific) _working_ directory.

Answer (score 15):

You should use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

For example in a windows services application:

`System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` will return **C:\Windows\system32**

While

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will return [Application.exe location]

Another important factor to note is that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is a readonly property while the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can be something else if necessary:

```
// Change the directory to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, you should use `BaseDirectory`.  `CurrentDirectory` could change over the course of the program's execution.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual studio 2010 test projects, if you enable deployment option of Edit test settings, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory points to the TestResults\Out folder(not bin\debug).
Although, default setting point to bin\debug folder.

Here I found convincing answer.

[Why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory not contains "bin" in asp.net app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669833/why-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-not-contains-bin-in-asp-net-app)

Answer (score 3):

I have also been through this few days back, as I was using

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

as it was giving me issue on the production server but was working fine with my local server,

So, I tried with

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

And it worked for me in both the Environment.

So, As all of them has said We should always go with

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

as it checks the Current Domain directory for the path.

have a look for more information

[Could not find a part of path error on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290793/could-not-find-a-part-of-path-error-on-server)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use something like:

```
            string AppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            AppPath = AppPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
```