# Get the assembly path but not the temporary path where the assembly is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nunit, mstest

I am really breaking my head for the simple unit testing i am writing!

```
[TestFixture]
Class A
{

  [TestMethod]
  public void test()
  {
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location // gives some temporary local path
  }

 }
```

All i want is to get the path of the assembly location (where my project folder resides) not some local or temporary folder.

This folder is what I get if I put a breakpoint: \AppData\Local\Temp\

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I tried doing this with both nUnit as well as MSTest microsoft's unit testing! Nothing helps.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in

Comment: actually this is used in the dll which I am testing! But, during the unit testing, this path is the path of the Temp folder. Since i can't change the dll code, I need the path of the assembly location!

Comment: Yes Its does behave in a funny way when used with Nunit. Please read the link that I send you thoroughly. You will find your answer in it. More precisely look at the second answer with 257 up-votes.

Comment: @Koushik: thanks for the link. But again, pls note that I can't modify the code of the dll that I am running and this statement is just inside that dll!

Comment: ok. If you want to get the path of the assembly that is being referenced in your application you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.Load("AssemblyName").Location)`.
But if you want to get the path of the main assembly that is a wrong way to do it because you are trying to access the assembly path of a different project that is in the same solution. As you know when you make a  reference, a copy of the dll is copied to the local directory and all the operations are done on it. So even if you remove the project from where the dll is reference it still works.
May be this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: actually this is used in the dll which I am testing! But, during the unit testing, this path is the path of the Temp folder. Since i can't change the dll code, I need the path of the assembly location!

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net, it doesn't work. I found a better covered solution at [Why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory not contains "bin" in asp.net app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669833/why-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-not-contains-bin-in-asp-net-app). It works for both Win Application and ASP.Net Web Application.

```
public string ApplicationPath
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath))
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; //exe folder for WinForms, Consoles, Windows Services
        }
        else
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath; //bin folder for Web Apps 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `GetExecutingAssembly()` isn't the executable you're expecting, why not just use a known type in the assembly you want.

```cs
typeof(A).Assembly.Location;
```