# DbMigration.SqlFile difference in base directory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

We are using the new DbMigration.SqlFile method in EF Migrations 6.1.2 to run a migration script in our migration. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sqlfile(v=vs.113).aspx), the file has to be relative to the current AppDomain BaseDirectory. We have included these files in the project, and set them to copy to output directory.
Locally this all runs fine. They get output to the bin directory, and run fine.

When deploying the software to a server running IIS however, the migration fails, because it suddenly expects the files to be relative to the root. When I copy them there, the migration works.

How can I use DbMigration.SqlFile so it runs correctly both locally and on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SqlFile` method uses the `CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` if a relative path is given. A workaround is to map the path yourself and give an absolute path to the method. A solution would look like this:

```
var sqlFile = "MigrationScripts/script1.sql";
var filePath = Path.Combine(GetBasePath(), sqlFile);
SqlFile(filePath);

public static string GetBasePath()          
{       
    if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null) return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
    else return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"bin");
}
```

BasePath solution taken from: [Why AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory not contains "bin" in asp.net app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669833/why-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-not-contains-bin-in-asp-net-app)

Answer (score 1):

We're using it like this from within the migration: `SqlFile(@"..\..\Sql\views\SomeView.sql");`