# ASP.NET Core configuration for .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, console-application

ASP.NET Core support a new configuration system as seen here:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Is this model also supported in .NET Core console applications?

If not what is alternate to the previous `app.config` and `ConfigurationManager` model?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use this code snippet. It includes Configuration and DI.

```
public class Program
{
    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory;
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Environment not found in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        Console.WriteLine("Environment: {0}", environment);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        if (environment == "Development")
        {

            builder
                .AddJsonFile(
                    Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, string.Format("..{0}..{0}..{0}", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), $"appsettings.{environment}.json"),
                    optional: true
                );
        }
        else
        {
            builder
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: false);
        }

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddDebug();

        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
            .AddDbContext<FmDataContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        services.AddTransient<IPackageFileService, PackageFileServiceImpl>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var packageFileService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPackageFileService>();

        ............
    }
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to add in the project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "includeFiles": [
        "appsettings.json",
        "appsettings.Integration.json",
        "appsettings.Production.json",
        "appsettings.Staging.json"
      ]
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Integration.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "appsettings.Staging.json"
    ]
  },
...
}
```

Comment: This answer is not ideal. Use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` instead of `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. There should be no need for the hack afterwards.

Comment: Or set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer" in Visual Studio for the JSON files.

Comment: For base dir to work in Web, Console and Winforms you can use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675039/1818723

Comment: Gary Woodfine described this in detail in a very good style on this post: https://garywoodfine.com/configuration-api-net-core-console-application/

Comment: @javad Only partly; I ended up here because I wanted the DI part, which he promised but I haven't found. He also didn't show how to use multiple config files as this example does.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `SetBasePath` method unless you add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`. And no `AddJsonFile` without `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Comment: `string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");` this is soooo amateurish. You can screw other apps by setting global variable. You can't run dev and prod together. MS quality decreased so much with netcore

Comment: The microservices with its own environment in docker changes the approach the normal application must ne written. It's the reality.

Comment: This snippet helped me a lot, with very small tweaks. Thanks

Answer (score 297):

For a .NET Core 2.0 console app, I did the following:

1. Create a new file named *appsettings.json* at the root of the project (the file name can be anything)
2. Add my specific settings to that file as json. For example:

> ```
> {
>   "myKey1" :  "my test value 1", 
>   "myKey2" :  "my test value 2", 
>   "foo" :  "bar" 
> }
> ```

3. Configure to copy the file to the output directory whenever the project is built *(in VS -> Solution Explorer -> right-click file -> select 'Properties' -> Advanced -> Copy to Output Directory -> select 'Copy Always')*
4. Install the following nuget package in my project:

   - *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json*
5. Add the following to *Program.cs* (or wherever `Main()` is located):

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

       var configuration = builder.Build();

       // rest of code...
   }
   ```
6. Then read the values using either of the following ways:

   ```
   string myKey1 = configuration["myKey1"];
   Console.WriteLine(myKey1);

   string foo = configuration.GetSection("foo").Value;
   Console.WriteLine(foo);
   ```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#simple-configuration

Comment: I'm getting an issue related to `IConfigurationAssembly` being in an assembly that is not referenced - despite the Abstractions assembly being referenced.  Ever see this?

Comment: I haven't. However, using `IConfigurationRoot` and not `IConfigurationAssembly`.

Comment: As I noticed Microsoft don't use IConfigurationRoot in their examples, but use IConfiguration.

Comment: IConfigurationRoot is not longer used in Core 2.0

Comment: [`IConfigurationRoot` is still available in .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Applies_to).  It inherits from `IConfiguration` but it's considered [a derived case of it that's not commonly used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#lf-content=225842398:758472358). Regardless, the code example has been updated to not include it and avoid any confusion.

Comment: 2 notes: on point 4, you only need Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json... It will include the other 2 by default. Second: If you want to load a section to an object, it is useful to know: var options = new FooOptions();
            ConfigurationBinder.Bind(configuration.GetSection("foo"), options);  You will need Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

Comment: public class FooOptions{ public string myKey1 {get; set;} public string myKey2 {get;set;}}

Comment: Only the package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json is required in the sample ;)

Comment: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console .. 
.. Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
.. Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
.. Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Comment: appsettings.json din't work for me, so used app_settings.json

Comment: +1. Much better than the accepted answer, IMHO. There's a lot of unnecessary bloat in the accepted answer's code.

Comment: @StevenRands I think the answer was accepted before most of the bloat was added, months after the original answer

Comment: PERFECTION dude, nicely written! I followed each step and got configurations working 1st time! Thanks.

Comment: using vs 2017 enterprise.   did a "using microsoft.extensions.configuration.json" and parts of the the builder syntax didn't look like they were being found by the compiler.   My code still doesn't show SetBasePath and AddJsonFile as found in an include (normal text not colored).  So if you think the routines aren't found, keep typing.   Then when you're done see if it compiles.

Comment: Does this load user secrets and environment variables?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal you will need to update de appsettings.json file and rebuild ConfigurationBuilder by yourself

Comment: @Ray yours is the best answer. It continues to work very well on .net 5

Answer (score 35):

If you use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` (version 2.1.0+) to host your console app and asp.net core app, all your configurations are injected with `HostBuilder`'s `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and `ConfigureHostConfiguration` methods. Here's the demo about how to add the `appsettings.json` and environment variables:

```
    var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (args != null)
            {
                // enviroment from command line
                // e.g.: dotnet run --environment "Staging"
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            builder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            // Override config by env, using like Logging:Level or Logging__Level
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        })
        ... // add others, logging, services
        //;
```

In order to compile above code, you need to add these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Comment: How is the environment determined? If I create a profile in launchSettings, it actually sets `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` but then `context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` is not being set correctly

Comment: You should use environment as the key, check this code: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/HostDefaults.cs

Comment: @FeiyuZhou that's a dead link

Comment: Isn't _all_ of this solution after `new HostBuilder()` redundant? Doesn't `HostBuilder` do it all internally?

Comment: @Auspex It depends on how you define your console app. If you need to define custom configurations then you should set like this. Here's the doc for dotnet core 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#host-configuration

Comment: Sure, if you want something custom, but you didn't _do_ anything custom, so the reader is going to think they have to do all that, when they likely don't. You might, for instance, have shown how to "use environment as the key", instead of posting a link, that is now dead, as a comment.

Comment: My answer is for dotnet core 2.0, and it's enough for config with environment and appsettings.json which i use in my product code. The link I commented is for dotnet core 3.0, which is the latest config code.

Comment: Not your second link, the first one to GitHub. That's a 404. Anyway, I'm still sure dotnet 2.x did what your code does—I stripped that stuff out when I upgraded from 1.x

Answer (score 12):

On .Net Core 3.1 we just need to do these:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
}
```

Using SeriLog will look like:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using System;


namespace yournamespace
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting Program.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Program terminated unexpectedly.");
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Serilog appsetings.json section for generating one file daily will look like:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\Logs\\Program.json",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: after trying all those syntax from all over the web, yours is the one that worked for me, and it's so simple.

Answer (score 11):

If you use .netcore 3.1 the simplest way use new configuration system to call `CreateDefaultBuilder` method of static class `Host` and configure application

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                IHostEnvironment env = context.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    // copy configuration files to output directory
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    // default prefix for environment variables is DOTNET_
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MySimpleService>();
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}

class MySimpleService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StartAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StopAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You need set Copy to Output Directory = 'Copy if newer' for the files `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{environment}.json`
Also you can set environment variable {prefix}*ENVIRONMENT (default prefix is DOTNET*) to allow choose specific configuration parameters.

.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication3</RootNamespace>
  <AssemblyName>ConsoleApplication3</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.7" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.7" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

more details [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host)

Comment: oh finally thank you for pointing me to the right direction!
It is so important to distinguish ASP.NET.CORE and DOTNET.CORE
If using a .NET Core application (not asp web stuff, but console or windows/linux services for microservices) you have to set the debugging environment variables to *DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT*. Then it will work with context.HostingEnviornment.EnviornmentName.

Answer (score 10):

I was mistaken. You can use the new `ConfigurationBuilder` from a netcore console application.

See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html for an example.

However, only aspnet core has dependency injection out of the box so you don't have the ability to have strongly typed configuration settings and automatically inject them using `IOptions`.

Comment: This answer is valid, but it should contain the necessary code, thus no upvote.

Comment: All you need is to add package: `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and call `service.AddOptions();`

Comment: The entire (very long) linked page seems to be ASP.NET related, with mention of "WebHost" in every example. I got to this SO question after finding the linked page and thinking "ok, that's ASP.NET, what about Console Apps".

Comment: That's a bit odd, @mackenir, because in 3.0 it's all been refactored so that it's all just Host! The only reference to WebHost itself is to point you to the 2.2 documentation. They could have been a little clearer that the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults()` calls in the examples are optional, and only for Web apps.

Answer (score 4):

It's something like this, for a dotnet 2.x core console application:

```
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

        [...]
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(options => options.AddConfiguration(configuration).AddConsole())
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration)
            .AddSingleton<SomeService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        [...]
        await serviceProvider.GetService<SomeService>().Start();
```

The you could inject ILoggerFactory, IConfiguration in the `SomeService`.

Answer (score 3):

**Install these packages:**

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT");
        Console.WriteLine("ENVIRONMENT: " + environmentName);

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
        var mySettingsConfig = configuration.Get<MySettingsConfig>();

        Console.WriteLine("URL: " + mySettingsConfig.Url);
        Console.WriteLine("NAME: " + mySettingsConfig.Name);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**MySettingsConfig Class:**

```
public class MySettingsConfig
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your appsettings can be as simple as this:
[image]

Also, set the appsettings files to Content / Copy if newer:
[image: content]

Answer (score 2):

Other solutions work but not in case that you want inject `IConfigurationRoot` in other services. I simply did it this way:

Install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton(_ =>
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                .Build())
        .BuildServiceProvider();

     // Rest of code ...
}
```

and in other services inject it or use

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationRoot>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LiteWare.Configuration](https://github.com/samsam07/LiteWare.Configuration) library for that. It is very similar to .NET Framework original `ConfigurationManager` and works for .NET Core/Standard. Code-wise, you'll end up with something like:

```
string cacheDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValue<string>("CacheDirectory");
ulong cacheFileSize = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValue<ulong>("CacheFileSize");
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of LiteWare.Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just piling on...  similar to Feiyu Zhou's post. Here I'm adding the machine name.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
          {
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            var hostname = Environment.MachineName;
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostname}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            if (args != null)
            {
              builder.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
          })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
  }
```