# .NET Core console application, how to configure appSettings per environment?

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 1.0.0 console application and two environments. I need to be able to use `appSettings.dev.json` and `appSettings.test.json` based on environment variables I set at run time. This seems to be quite straight forward for ASP.NET Core web applications, via dependency injection and IHostingEnvironment and the EnvironmentName env. variable, however how should I wire things up for the console application (besides writing my own custom code that uses `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This is how we do it in our `.netcore` console app. The key here is to include the right **dependencies** on your project namely (*may be not all, check based on your needs*) and **copy to output** the appSetting.json as part of your **buildoptions**

```json
  {
    "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
       "include": [
       "appsettings*.json",
       "App*.config"
                 ]
          }
},
```

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace MyApp
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
       

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        var configuration = builder.Build();
        var myConnString= configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConn");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have eventually ended up using a more convoluted version of that, using `new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables()` and finding `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: I don't seem to find a buildoptions in the console app.

Comment: I think you should add a nuget `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` nuget package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=basicconfiguration#json-configuration

Comment: shouldn't `Configuration = builder.Build();` be `IConfigurationRoot Configuration = builder.Build();`?

Comment: how will this Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") work without reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting ?

Comment: @HaBo It won't, you'll need to run something like `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Test");`  or set the environment variable in your environment. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: With the new csproj structure you would   <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Please update your answer. Apparently there is no need in json part of your code example...

Comment: Also need to ensure that all versions of appsettings.json (e.g. appsettings.Development.json) are set to 'copy if newer' so that they go to output directory as well.

Comment: I  can't believe this is the accepted solution. What if I have both dev and prod running on the same machine? What if I forget that some app is running and change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT? This is soooo amateurish and so much inferior to classic .NET

Comment: @Toolkit TBH, I'm still trying to understand why you would use `var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");` in the first place.  If you have to do something like `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Test");` then why not just set `var environmentName = "Test";` and be done with the hack?

Comment: @ArvoBowen They are only reading the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in code not setting it.  If you put the code "var environmentName = "Test";" in your program how would you run it in production?

Comment: Add nuget Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 35):

As of Net Core 3.1++, the generic Host class Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host uses DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT environment variable instead of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

Setting `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Development"` in Project Debug settings will work without any additional coding.

Or you can add your own prefix like this:

```
// works for WPF but should work similar for Console Apps
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IHost _host;

    public App()
    {
        _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => {
                configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                ConfigureServices(context.Configuration, services);
            })
            .Build();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 30):

For those who are using .NET Core version 2.1.0+ and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting to host your console app, you can use the following code (according to the Feiyu Zhou's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828537/680032) in another thread):

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            // enviroment from command line
            // e.g.: dotnet run --environment "Staging"
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        }
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    })
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two `IHostingEnvironment` interfaces that you should use. One is for ASP.NET Core Applications, the other one is for .NET Core Console applications. You can use this code example for both:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal;

namespace MyApplication.Common
{
    public static class ConfigurationFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use for ASP.NET Core Web applications.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            return Configure(config, env.EnvironmentName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use for .NET Core Console applications.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            return Configure(config, env.EnvironmentName);
        }

        private static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, string environmentName)
        {
            return config
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use for .NET Core Console applications.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
        {
            var env = new HostingEnvironment
            {
                EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production",
                ApplicationName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
                ContentRootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                ContentRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            };

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var configured = Configure(config, env);
            return configured.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console App "version"  namespace "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" ,  interface "IHostingEnvironment" , assembly file : "microsoft.extensions.hosting.abstractions\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll"

Comment: Here is the list of nuget packages I had to add to get this code to work.      <PackageReference I="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference I="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference I="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference I="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference I="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.1.1" />

Comment: Should I create a dependency of Microsoft.AspNetCore namespace in a console app project?

Comment: So I just updated my code for 3.1.  Next comments are the csproj.  The "abstractions" 2.1.1 does not exist in 3.1.  You have to use a "FrameworkReference". Note, it'll take 2 extra comments to give the germane csproj code.

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.0" />

Comment: </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Comment: This answer should be updated as it currently uses depreciated code.  You should remove the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;` statement and clearly define the new suggested interfaces typed out completely in this case.  "Use for ASP.NET Core Web applications.": `public static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env)` and "Use for .NET Core Console applications.": `private static IConfigurationBuilder Configure(IConfigurationBuilder config, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment env)`.

Comment: I don't understand why all this needs to be done though.  When I'm running my console app in the IDE "EnvironmentName" always comes back as `NULL`.  Then I end up with it adding the JSON file `appsettings..json` to the mix.  Should this be giving me an "EnvironmentName" of something like "Debug"?  I'm calling `IConfiguration _config = ConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration();` from my console's Main() method.  Should I be using it differently?

Answer (score 9):

If like me, you're simply trying to have a different configuration file for Release and Development mode, just add a appsettings.Development.json file with CopyToOutputDirectory setting set to true in the file's property window.

Now, to access the file depending on the build configuration, you can use the #if DEBUG [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Here's an example :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

#if DEBUG
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", true, true);
#else
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);
#endif

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    // ... use configuration
}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution as it can hide compilation errors, which then become apparent once you push to a build server and the directive becomes true/false. It's much better to use an environment variable. I'm not judging though - I have done this in the past many times, it's just that I've run into the issue I mentioned a few times.

Comment: I'd recommend that you *always* add the `appsettings.json` file (which addresses @jcvandan's issue of never loading it) and `#if DEBUG` *also* load the `appsettings.Development.json` - the standard way is to allow the Development to override settings if required, not having to specify them all.

Comment: `#if DEBUG` is what I use, but only to set the environment variable to `Development` or otherwise `Production` by default. I have found for console apps, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` always returns `Production` unless you use a launchSettings.json file (or other more buried tweak) which none of these solutions mention. With the default VS template and default console app template, this is the only solution that works to simply have a Development environment with no extra configs.

Answer (score 3):

These environment things seems to work for most ppl, but I don't aggree at all with all that environmental management. Whether the runtime nor the target system knows what it is. Only you, as a developer or a deployment mechanism, knows what the target system is.

Everyone is talking about ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable, even official documentation like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.0. But in fact someone has to define a system explicitly as production system for example, by setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT manually once. Do you really want to assume and rely on it that this is already set in every environment you use? No, you can't. What if you have to deploy a console app to a batch server  where no website is running? ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not available. What if you need to deploy and run a .net core webapi without IIS, only with kestrel? No web.config and no environment variable. Do you want your admins/operation team to set this misleading variable for your console app? In this context i've seen lots of projects which have appsettings like this per project:

```
appsettings.json
appsettings.development.json
appsettings.test.json
appsettings.uat.json
appsettings.staging.json
appsettings.production.json
```

Keep in mind that by default each of these files will be published and also be deployed to the target system. At a first look it looks very easy to let the environment "decide" which config should be used. But you have configuration and also potentially credentials deployed on a system which is not intended for it.

Conclusion

I recommend appsettings.json + appsettings.release.json. First one is only for dev. Change it, play with it like you want. Last one is a VALID config ready for deployment (process). Before deployment starts, transform the config to be ready for the target system. That's it. No need to rely on settings on the target machine, no messy configs. Keep full control of your app even when servers change quickly (like scaling in general, VMs, cloud, whatever)

I appreciate constructive feedback :-)

Comment: You're missing the point somewhat and yes, the condition could be determined by a configuration value instead of an environment variable.

I have different app behavior in Web API's where I use swagger for developers to examine and test endpoints. 
Having a consistent release management process of promoting the same binaries through to a Production environment, this feature needs to be toggled. Whether that is achieved by config setting per app/environment or a single environment variable is irrelevant except environment settings apply to all apps on the same server, unlike app configs.

Comment: No one has to define a system as production system explicitly because this is the default.
But you as a developer define YOUR own system as development environment and override default production settings with those in your *.development.json files.

Answer (score 2):

It's something like this, for a dotnet 2.x core console application:

```
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

        [...]
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(options => options.AddConfiguration(configuration).AddConsole())
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration)
            .AddSingleton<SomeService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        [...]
        await serviceProvider.GetService<SomeService>().Start();
```

The you could inject ILoggerFactory, IConfiguration in the `SomeService`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone on .NetCore 3.1 and using the .CreateDefaultBuilder(args) extension. Just add -environment "Development" to your command line arguments in the Debug settings. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, this is all provided automatically by the default host builder.  The only code required to include the correct appsettings file based on environment, command-line arguments, environment variables, user secrets (for Development environment only), etc is to use the default builder:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        // configure services here
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

The key is to use the `CreateDefaultBuilder()` method which pre-configures all of these sources.  You can also layer additional sources such as in-memory collection using the fluent api which will take precedence over the formerly mentioned sources.

Sources:

[.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host)

[Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for ASP.Net Core environment variable (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT): -

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System;

public class Program {
    private static string HostingEnvironment => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    private static bool IsEnvironment(string environmentName) => HostingEnvironment?.ToLower() == environmentName?.ToLower() && null != environmentName;

    private static bool Development => IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
    private static bool Production => IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Production);
    private static bool Staging => IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Staging);

    public static void Main(string[] args) { // Your code here }
}
```

Then you can simply use the property

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (Development){
            // Blow up the planet
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question was not about asp.net core.

Comment: I know, but the *only* things about this that are remotely asp.net core related are the name of the environment variable and the .net core library used to get the string constants for 'Development', 'Staging' & 'Production'.

I thought it would be useful to use a legitimate environment variable instead of one I made up. It could be anything and not be in an asp.net core application at all.

Comment: Is this one (and its siblings) more "NON asp.net (core)" 'ish ?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.environmentname.development

Answer (score 0):

hai i used like this to get BaseURL of api to call from console app
cnfiguring .json file

```
 public  class Helper
    {
        public static string GetConfigurationItems()
        {
            string? url;
            ConfigurationItems cf = new ConfigurationItems();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            configuration.GetSection("ConfigurationItem").Bind(cf);
            url= cf.BaseURL;
            return url;
        }
       
    }
```

this is appsetting.json file

```
    {
  "ConfigurationItem": {
      "BaseURL": "https://localhost:46356"
    }
  }
```

this is concating baseUrl and route of api

```
            string apiURL = Helper.GetConfigurationItems() + 
"api/Employee/getAllEmployees";
```

**and change setting of appsetting.json file in properties: copy to output directory = copy alway**

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468370/1041457) shared by @Merilix2 but that didn't help me.

For **.NET Core 7**, the following worked for me in the Console application.

1. Right-click on Project and select the last option *Properties*.
2. Go to **Debug** and then select *General*.
3. Click on link *Open debug launch profiles UI*
4. In the opened window search for the **Environment variables** option. Set *Name* and *Value* where *Name* is the key.

The below screenshot can help much better way.

[image: How to use appsettings as per environment in Console app]

You **must set** the *Copy to Output Directory* as *Copy always* for appsettings.Develoment.json or one as per your environment.

[image: Properties window for appsettings.Development.json file]

I missed sharing that I have `ConfigurationBuilder` set like this.

```
private static ConfigurationBuilder GetConfigBuilder()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    return builder;
}
```