# .NET Core 2.0 no Microsoft.Extensions

Tags: .net-core, configuration

I tried to load configuration file like they do it in this post:
[.NET Core console application, how to configure appSettings per environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573571/net-core-console-application-how-to-configure-appsettings-per-environment)
but in my project namespace Microsoft doesn't contains Extensions namespace

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Extensions are not part of .NETStandard.  They would make it non-standard.  You'll have to add the Nuget package and fret about what it will take if you need to run this on another platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from Nuget package manager.

Comment: Yep... great solution :D Thanks