# NLog config set connection string from docker run argument

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nlog

I have a .NET Core api project that needs to run in a Docker container. The project uses NLog to log data to a database. I want to set the connection string property in the nlog.config file when running the container.

The app will be deployed to different clients and will use their databases for logging.

This is how I tried to configure the connection string in the nlog.config file:

```
...
  <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
      <connectionString>'${environment:logs_connection_string}'</connectionString>
      <dbProvider>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data</dbProvider>
...
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Service/Service.csproj", "Service/"]
COPY ["Extensions/CustomExtensions.csproj", "Extensions/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Service/Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Service"
RUN dotnet build "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
ARG log_connection
ENV logs_connection_string=$log_connection
```

These are some of my attepmts to pass the connection string on run:

- docker run -e log_connection="connection_string" -itd -p 1234:80 --name service service
- docker run -e log_connection_string="connection_string" -itd -p 1234:80 --name service service

I don't have much experience in using Docker, so this approach may not even be doable. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: NLog should not have any issues with looking up Environment variables. See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Environment-Layout-Renderer. Have you tried to enable NLog InternalLogger and check what connectionstring is resolved. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Konrad Botor's answer is doable as he has provied a very good answer, but there is a simpler way for my use case.
@RolfKristensen's comment pointed me into the right direction.

An ASP.NET Core application loads the environement's variables by default (see this answer on SO: [Using AddEnvironmentVariables in .net core 3.1 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079740/using-addenvironmentvariables-in-net-core-3-1-app)). Environment variables passed when running the image, can be accessed in the app by using:

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("env_name")`.

As @RolfKristensen's mentioned, NLog knows how to load environment variables. The connection string tag in the nlog.config file looks like this:

`<connectionString>${environment:CONNECTION_STRING}</connectionString>`

The run command looks like this.

```
docker run -itd -p 1234:80 --name test -e CONNECTION_STRING="..." app
```

The connection string will be loaded correctly from the variable passed at run.

For passing sensitive data, this approach is a security risk, as the docker run command will remain in the command history. But someone can use a composer file or pass the host's environment variables to the run command to mitigate the risk.

**EDIT**

I use the Dockerfile generated by Visual Studio.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Service/Service.csproj", "Service/"]
COPY ["Extensions/CustomExtensions.csproj", "Extensions/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Service/Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Service"
RUN dotnet build "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither `ARG` nor `ENV` is meant for what you want to accomplish.

What you need is  some sort of entrypoint script that will read the environment variable you're setting in run command (either `log_connection` or `log_connection_string` in your examples), reacts with error or setting it to a default value if it is not set and finally edits `nlog.config` and sets value of  `<connectionString>` to the value of the variable and finally runs `dotnet Service.dll`.

For example you could set your connection thing in `nlog.config` like so:

```
<connectionString>log_connection_string</connectionString>
```

Then create file `run.ps1` with content as follows:

```
#!/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
if (-not (Test-Path env:log_connection_string)) { $env:log_connection_string = 'default value for log_connection_string' }
((Get-Content -Path path\to\nlog.config -Raw) -replace 'log_connection_string',$Env:log_connection_string) | Set-Content -Path path\to\nlog.config
dotnet Service.dll
```

copy it to directory `/app` during image build

and replace the last three lines of your Dockerfile with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.ps1"]
```

Edit:
To install Powershell Core in your base image use the following command in Dockerfile (just below `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base` would be best):

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb --output packages-microsoft-prod.deb --silent && \
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y powershell && \
apt-get clean
```

You also need to either make `run.ps1` executable or change entrypoint to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh", "-Command","./run.ps1`enter code here`"]
```

Alternatively you can use an equivalent script in Bash (let's name it `run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z "$log_connection_string" ]] && export log_connection_string="default value for log_connection_string"
sed -i 's/log_connection_string/'"$log_connection_string"'/' path\to\nlog.config
dotnet Service.dll
```

And entrypoint should be set to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./run.sh"]
```

Final note: there is no law that prevents one from using lowercase names for environmental variables, but it's a generally accepted convention to write the in all caps, eg. `LOG_CONNECTION_STRING` instead of `log_connection_string`.

Comment: I forgot to mention something, the docker image is compiled for a linux host environment. Will the powershell part run in that scenario?

Comment: If the image has PowerShell installed (and yes, PS has a Linux version), it should, although I think you would need to change `ENTRYPOINT` to `["/path/to/pwsh", "-Command", "./run.ps1"]`. If not you will have to install it (see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell for details) in the image or write analogous scrpit in whatever shell is installed in the image.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am out of office for a couple of days. I will check the solution when I get back.