# Value is returned as null while reading appsetting key as environment variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and I am adding a key in `appsettings.json` file and trying to read this as environment variable:

```
var x = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FILE_STORAGE")?.ToUpper();
```

The value is returned as `null`.

I have added below code in the `program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;
configuration
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "FILE_STORAGE": "Azure"
}
```

I know I can read through `IConfiguration` (`_configuration["FILE_STORAGE"]`), but can I read like `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FILE_STORAGE")`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079740/using-addenvironmentvariables-in-net-core-3-1-app this might answer your query.

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  Usually you would set an env variable to override the value in the appsettings file, and not write code to read the environment variable directly.  Your code already applies all the environment variables to the configuration object.

Comment: In other words, your code does not set any environment variables.  Rather, it reads environment variables and tries to override the values from appsettings in IConfiguration if they exist as environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` reads the Environment Variable, not the value from settings files, such as appsettings.json!

[image]

You should use `_configuration["FILE_STORAGE"]`, then it will first try to read your environment variable `FILE_STORAGE`, if there is no value - read from appsettings.json

I'd recommend
`var value = _configuration.GetValue<string>("FILE_STORAGE");`

See [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-providers)

Comment: wow! so easy to get it. Thanks and appreciate @Roman Marusyk

Comment: Glad to have been of help