# How to read JSON file into string specifying values and using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console application (not an ASP.NET Core) with SQL Server connection, where connection string is stored in appsettings.json file

```
{"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection":"Server=sqlserver;Database=appDb;User=username;Password=password;" }}
```

Previously I used Json.Net to read a string

```
var connString = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json")).GetValue("ConnectionStrings").SelectToken("DefaultConnection").ToString()
```

and it worked fine.
Now I decided to switch to System.Text.Json library and having issues with dynamic deserialization.
The following code throws an exception:

```
var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>("appsettings.json");
```

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: ''a' is an invalid start of a value.
>   Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.' Inner Exception
>   JsonReaderException: 'a' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0
>   | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Then I would read from a dictionary specifying Where Key == "ConnectionStrings", and then subsequent Value of string array == "DefaultConnection". I did not reach that point yet, because of an Exception, so I did not planned how to read from a Dictionary yet.

How can I use a new System.Text.Json library to read a connection string from appsettings.json file?
Is it correct to deserialize to `Dictianory<string, string[]>`? Or it would be better to use `Dictianory<string, Dictianory<string, string>>`?

Comment: Maybe this way is better for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40620561/982149 , see also: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/setting-up-net-core-configuration-providers/

Comment: @Fildor it's excellent. Works as charm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JsonSerializer.Deserialize` expects a JSON string, not the name of a file.

You need to load the file into a string and then pass that to the `Deserialize` method:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");
var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. By the way, it couldn't convert to string[], so I changed to Dictianory<string, Dictianory<string, string>>

Answer (score 3):

One of the benefits of `System.Text.Json` is that it can easily and efficiently deserialize directly from a `Stream`. When reading JSON from I/O such as a file or HTTP request, it's better to just deserialize the `Stream` directly and avoid the unnecessary allocations and memory required to read it into a string first.

```cs
using var reader = new StreamReader("appsettings.json");
var dict = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(reader.BaseStream);
```

That being said, for the specific case of reading the `appsettings.json`, it's better to use the [configuration tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) built-in to the .NET Generic Host instead of manually parsing the JSON. This gives added benefits such as the ability to override these settings using environment variables and/or command line switches, as well as more easily moving them to another storage system such as KeyVault.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the api in JsonDocument for this purpose:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");
var appSettings = JsonDocument.Parse(json, new JsonDocumentOptions { CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip });
var result = appSettings.RootElement.GetProperty("ConnectionStrings").GetProperty("DefaultConnection").GetString();
```

HTH