# DotNet Core 2 Console Application Configuration

Tags: .net-core-2.0

The Core 1.x configuration has been answered here

[ASP.NET Core configuration for .NET Core console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114761/asp-net-core-configuration-for-net-core-console-application)

Unfortunately the Core 2.0.0 API and architecture has changed slightly and by [the looks of this article](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/05/25/asp-net-core-2-0-configuration-and-razor-pages/)  that it uses Dependency Injection on the Startup class now (on a WebAPI based project) which is allot simpler.

But I am not sure how to do that on a Console application as there is no underlying DI. When I try to use the following code none of the methods exist on the new 2.0.0

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true) -ERROR
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true) -ERROR
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(); -ERROR
```

Does any body know how to add `appsettings.json` into the ConfigurationBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I have to manually add this package which contains the **AddJsonFile** extension - For some reason Intellisense did not suggest installing this package as it does with other things.

```
dependencies {
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "2.0.0"
}
```