# Environment.CurrentDirectory returns odd results

Tags: c#, dll

I have some issues with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, it sometimes goes to the `System32` folder. I looked online and found out why this happens and what alternatives I have (like `Application.StartupPath` and stuff like that) but the problem is the code is in a `.dll` that I am using and I can't edit it (or can I).

Is there anything I can do about this?

EDIT: In the duplicate issue the person writes their own dll. I don't own the dll I'm having problems with and I can't change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764680/how-to-get-the-location-of-the-dll-currently-executing

Comment: You aren't quite clear what the problem is. Does the dll (i can just assume you don't have the source for that dll) changes the CurrentDirectory so your own code fails using CurrentDirectory? Or something changes CurrentDirectory and something in that dll fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the location of the DLL currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764680/how-to-get-the-location-of-the-dll-currently-executing)

Comment: If you are not sure what is causing this, then simply remember current directory on application startup and when you need to work with it either restore it or simply use the value to create absolute paths everywhere. Another thing is that your application can be executed by something else what set working directory to something you don't expect, then don't use `CurrentDirectory`, but a [more safe approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10993869/1997232) to retrieve directory where exe-file is located.

Comment: @Sinatr, @ikkentim, I cannot modify anything in the .dll as I stated, it does its own stuff and whoever made it chose (unfortunately) to use `CurrentDirectory`. @Ralf, the problem I get is that it can't find the .dll in `System32` returned by `CurrentDirectory`, which of course is only natural.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to grab the path directly from the executable if `CurrentDirectory` is giving you an issue:

```
 private void GetFilePath()
        {
            string filepath = string.Empty;

            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("exe name");
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                filepath = process.MainModule.FileName;
            }

            return filepath;
        }
```