# C# - Get path of project , without bin folder in path

Tags: c#

I try to get current directory path of my project .
I tried:

1. > System.IO.Directory.GetDirectoryRoot();
2. > Environment.CurrentDirectory;
3. > System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\");

and in all option I get :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\

Instead of project path .

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you mean the project path, as in the path where your .csproj project file from Visual Studio resides?

Comment: `this.GetType().Assembly.Location`.

Comment: Yes, `executing assembly` != `project file`. Which do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a link on the net : [Should I use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or System.Environment.CurrentDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current)

You should use : `string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ;`

Indeed, the others are values which can change during the program's execution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this out:

`string thePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;`

Not sure if it works for you, but you can always try.