# Installing .NET Windows Service with the Visual Studio installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I installed .NET Windows Service with the Visual Studio installer. In the code, I'm using the following code to write to the log file:

```
Appdomain.currentdomain.basedirectory+\\Logfile.txt".
```

Where can I find the log file `log file.txt` after installation? If I install through the command prompt, it's available under that directory, but I want to install the service through the Visual Studio installer only.

Also, what is the best place to install the service in servers?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current#674865 helps you any