# How to retrieve the repository directory name I am in using C#?

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, repository

So I am currently working using a Unity project in a specific repository. How can I get the name of this repository I am working in? That is, the name of the folder directly above the .git folder.

The way I have done it is like so:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().GetParentDirectory().GetParentDirectory().GetParentDirectory().GetFilename();
```

However, this feels like not the best way to do it since it's almost like as if I am hard coding?

What other ways can I do this?

Comment: Is this specifically for the editor or do you need this name also at play time on end user's device?

Comment: Specifically for the editor only as I want to display this repo directory name on an editor window. So not for during the play time at all.

Comment: Consider running `git rev-parse --git-dir` to locate the actual repository storage directory, or—probably better—`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find the top level of the working tree. Use these plus the current working directory to get the path you want. Git also has `--show-cdup` which will show the number of `../` operations required to climb to the top of the working tree.

Comment: @torek I like this method and it worked. I used `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` specifically which gave me the repository path. After that I just did `.GetFilename()` on the path string and it gave me the repository name itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably start with a known folder like e.g. [`Application.dataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) which is the `Assets` folder and from there bubble up until you find the root

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath);
while(directory.GetDirectories(".git").Length == 0)
{
    directory = directory.Parent;

    if(directory == null)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("We went all the way up to the system root directory and didn't find any \".git\" directory!");
    }
}
var repositoryPath = directory.FullName;
var repositoryName = directory.Name;
```

You could pobably also start at

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

which usually should be the root path of your project, so basically already one directory higher than the `Assets`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the folder of your code when you run your game:

You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current)

Comment: This returns the path of the Unity editor executable e.g. `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.8f1\Editor` and is not quite what OP is looking for ;)