# Find the path of the folder containing the executable of a service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm having some issues with a library that cannot find the path of its config file.
The reason beeing that my program is deployed in a directory and installed as a service using sc.exe.
When trying to locate the file in this case, it looks in System32 and cannot find it.

I can provide a full path to this library to solve the issue, however, **how can I reference the folder of the executable called by the service in c# ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you're looking for:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Ref: [Should I use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or System.Environment.CurrentDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current)